# How do I handle invalid URI in POCO

Tags: c++, client-server, poco, poco-libraries

I want to handle a invalid URI client request in `createRequestHandler(HTTPServerRequest& request)` function in subclassed `HTTPRequestHandlerFactory`.

I want to send response that the URI is invalid with error code

> HTTP_NOT_FOUND ( 404 ).

```
RequestHandler * RequestHandlerFactory::createRequestHandler(const Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request)
{
  // -- handleRequest -- 

  if ( request.getURI() != ExpectedURI ) 
  {
    // How do I send response to client that the URI is invalid?
    // Example I need to send HTTP_NOT_FOUND 
  }
}
```

Comment: It really depends on what *part* of the URI that's invalid. If if's the path then  it's typically a 404 reply.

Comment: Are you familiar with HTTP error codes? You need to specify _why_ it's invalid. This is regardless of the technology used. Perhaps the most common HTTP error code is 404, but that means "URI is valid, but I just don't have anythign by that name"

Comment: Assume that I need to send HTTP_NOT_FOUND. In that case, please help me to handle it?

Answer (score -1):

```
void sendErrorResponse(HTTPResponse::HTTPStatus status, const std::string& message)
{
    response().setStatusAndReason(status);
    std::string statusAndReason(NumberFormatter::format(static_cast<int>(response().getStatus())));
    statusAndReason += " - ";
    statusAndReason += response().getReason();
    std::string page("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>");
    page += statusAndReason;
    page += "</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>";
    page += statusAndReason;
    page += "</H1>";
    page += "<P>";
    page += message;
    page += "</P></BODY></HTML>";
    response().sendBuffer(page.data(), page.size());
}

if (request.getURI() != ExpectedURI) 
{
    sendErrorResponse(HTTPResponse::HTTP_NOT_FOUND, request.getURI());
}
```